# Access File from Other Solution Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have two projects , both are web applications. In my web application I have a upload page to allow users to upload their files. I used Server.MapPath(@"~/something/") for the directory, but how do I retrieve that file in my other application For download?

For both i use

```
 string fileName = "SomeFile";
 string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/something/") + fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may create request response page
in which
one application is request file to another one 
and second application give response with file attachment
at receiver end page receive response as stream off byte and convert to specific extension.

Answer (score 0):

The "~" in Server.MapPath stays for the application root and you can't use it if your upload folder is not under it. I would suggest to have a configuration key in the web.config and use it to determine the upload path.

[How to: Read Application Settings from the Web.config File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx)